# learning laravel excel import function

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import

$titles = Item::lists('title')->toArray();

i got error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Item' not found" sorry but i just started laravel this day :'(

i just got this code here in stackoverflow :(

```
public function excel_import(Request $request){
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file_name= $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('files',$file_name);
        $titles = Item::lists('title')->toArray();
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load('files/'.$file_name, function($reader) {
            $reader->all();
        })->get();
        if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
            $insert = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (in_array($value->title, $titles))
                    continue;
                    $insert[] = array(
    'ke_y'   =>  $value['ke_y'], 
'en'     =>  $value['en'], 
       );
                    $titles[] = $value->title;

                }
            }
            if(!empty($insert)){
                DB::table('matrix_localization')->insert($insert);
                echo "all good. ";
            }
            else {
                echo "Please Check your file, Something is wrong there.";
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hello! It helps people if you post code that anyone can execute on their machines. That makes it then more easy to help you. See this site: [mcve]

Comment: Add an import statement at the top: `use Item;`

Answer (score 2):

first of all you have to create a model with the name "Item" using this command

```
php artisan make:model Item
```

2. now add this model in your controller namespace

```
use App\Item;
```

now you can use this Item class any where in your controller